# C++ execution order and increment statem

Tags: c++, increment, execution

Trying to better understand the following.
Before each statement I assign a=5;

1. ++a=1+a++;   // a is 6 now
2. a=a+1+a++;   // a is 11 now
3. a+=1+a++;    // a is 12 now
4. ++a+=1+a++;  // a is 13 now

Can someone explain the execution order to get these results or point to some examples/documentation?
Thank you.
I get what needs to happen to get these results, trying to gain a deeper understanding of the rules.

Comment: Before C++17, you have UB. For after, read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order (item 20))

Comment: And [evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) so `++a = b` is `(++a) = b` and not `++(a = b)`.